# Getting window height with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So basically, I want a div called #content to have a css top value of 200px if the browser height is less than 440px. However, this seems to not be working. What am I doing wrong?

```
var boh = $(window).height();
var bohi = parseInt(boh);
if(bohi < 440) {
    $("#content").css("top","200px");
} else {
    //this part works, so it's hidden
}
```

Comment: Is `#content` already `position: absolute` or `relative`?

Comment: Do you need it to work once? Or does it need to listen to the height changes and adjust accordingly? in which case you might want to use a CSS **media query**.

Comment: Your code appears correct. You probably just need to set your div to have fixed or absolute positioning. Can you post your html/css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to handle $(window).resize() event or that logic is only going to be run once.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).resize(function(){
  var bohi = $(window).height();
  if(bohi < 440) {
      $("#content").css("top","200px");
  } else {
      //this part works, so it's hidden
  }    
});

</script>
```

Here is a jsfiddle that seems to be working:

- http://jsfiddle.net/kNbuy/

Note that `$(window).height()` doesn't need the `parseInt()` its already treated as a number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place this code in your document ready handler like so:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

var boh = $(window).height();
var bohi = parseInt(boh);
if(bohi < 440) {
    $("#content").css("top","200px");
} else {
    //this part works, so it's hidden
}

});

</script>
```

Comment: Matt, can you explain why this needs to be in $(document).ready?  I think that you shouldn't have to wait for this event for the JavaScript to execute.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to make a difference for me. I uploaded a slimmed down version here: http://andrewsuzuki.com/jqtest.html

Answer (score 0):

OK. I think I see what your problem could be.

You haven't specified what the 'position' attribute of your #content element is.  If you're not getting the behavior you want, I suggest that you try adding `position:absolute` to the style for #content.

I recommend that you carefully study how the 'position' attribute works.  You may be surprised by the results you get by changing the position css attribute of #content *and* it's parent element.

Also, you may want to consider having the page automatically execute some code to adjust itself whenever the user resizes the browser window.  This can be handled with $.resize().

Comment: Hmm, it was already absolute. You can see it here: http://andrewsuzuki.com/jqtest.html

Answer (score 0):

As of 2015, I recommend using CSS media queries for this instead of JavaScript.

```
@media (max-height: 440px) {

    #content {
        top: 200px;
    }

}
```